# how do i perform a math operation in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

i am trying to calculate the `new_balance` when a user withdraw any amount from thier `main balance`.

i am trying to perform this operation when the form is being submitted but i do not know if this is the perfect way to perform this operations. This is what i am trying to achive.

```
def withdrawal_request(request):
    ...
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = WithWithdrawalRequestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_form = form.save(commit=False)
            new_form.user = request.user

            if new_form.amount > all_earning:
                messages.warning(request, "You cannot withdraw more than what is in your wallet balance.")
                return redirect("core:withdrawal-request")
            elif pending_payout > new_balance:
                messages.warning(request, "You have reached your wallet limit")
                return redirect("core:withdrawal-request")
            else:
                new_form.save()
                new_balance = new_balance - new_form.amount
                messages.success(request, f"Withdrawal Request Is Been Processed...")
                return redirect("core:withdrawal-request")
        
    else:
        form = WithWithdrawalRequestForm(request.POST)
        

    context = {
            "form":form,
            "new_balance":new_balance,
        }
    return render(request, "core/withdrawal-request.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually missing one more line

```
else:
   new_form.save()
   request.user.profile.main_all_earning = main_all_earning - new_form.amount
   request.user.profile.save()
   messages.success(request, f"Withdrawal Request Is Been Processed...")
   return redirect("core:withdrawal-request")
```